# Find the image of some circles for the transformation $w=1/z$.

Tags: complex-analysis

For the transformation $w=1/z$, find the image of

(a) the circle $|z-2|=1$

(b) the circle $|z-1|=2$

(c) the circle $|z-1|=1$

For (c), it's simple since $z=1/w$, so we get $|1-w|=|w|$, which is the straight line Re$z$=1/2.

However, for (a) and (b), I'm stuck. I tried to find it using the equation $z=x+iy, w=u+iv$, then $x=\frac{u}{u^2+v^2}, y=\frac{-v}{u^2+v^2}$. However, plugging this into the original equation, I get a very complicated equation that I cannot simplify. How may I approach (a) and (b)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewrite $w=1/z$ as $z=1/w$. I'll do the part (a).

It follows that $z-2=1/w-2$, and the condition $|z-2|=1$ implies that

$$
\left\lvert \frac{1}{w} -2 \right\rvert =1 \implies |1-2w|=|w|
$$

(at this point one may refer to Apollonius' theorem to see that this is equation of circle)

Now you may write $w=u+iv$ to see that above is equivalent to

$$
(1-2u)^2+4v^2=u^2+v^2 \implies 3u^2+3v^2-4u+1=0 \implies u^2+v^2-\frac{4}{3}u +\frac{1}{3}=0
$$

and last equation can be written as $(u-2/3)^2+v^2-\frac{1}{9}=0$ which you should recognize as a circle.

You should be able to do part (b) now.

Comment: Can I ask you how (1−2)^2+4^2=^2+^2 was made?